# How to install swift core libraries in production ubuntu server?

Tags: swift, ubuntu, vapor

I've two ubuntu server 22.04.4 machines. One is in local for development and another one is in server for deployment.

I tested the release build in the local and transfer the executable from local folder `.build/release/App` to server `App`. In the local server `App` is running from any folder not only `.build/release/App`

When I use command `./Server ServerApp --env production` then there is an error message,

> ./Server: error while loading shared libraries: libswiftCore.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I really thought that `swift build --configuration release` will build standalone binary executable.

> In this modern era I really didn't expected the final executable needs runtime libraries instead of using standard operating system API's.

But seems I need [run time libraries](https://www.swift.org/documentation/core-libraries/) and I searched lot can't able to find instructions to setup production server. Literally I am new to this. How can I setup and resolve that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the static linking flag during the build:

```
swift build -c release --static-swift-stdlib
```

That will produce a binary you can copy around as long as the underlying OS and architecture is the same

Comment: Works good but It's increases the overall binary size to 2x of existing. A simple server is around 120 MB. Thank you for your answer really helped me lot.

Comment: Correct because the binary has to include all the Swift runtime files you'd otherwise need. There's ongoing work to improve that and be cleverer about what gets pulled in